# RA layer request failed svn: Unable to connect to a repository at URL "my url"

Tags: svn

I am a new man in programer and my English is poor.I just want to know I just downloaded the file from  the url,but now I can't connect to it any more except  I reboot my computer!I mean ,I can't submit my files and download any file from the url,and all these thing will be done if I reboot my computer (it works just in the first ten minutes since I reboot computer,later,it don't work again).
all above is about svn  plugin in eclipse,developer about android..
my god ,can you tell me ?thank you!

Answer (score 1):

goto eclipse ---> `preferences`---> `Team` ---> `SVN`
 find SVN interface,
 change client to `SVNKit`

or

install the svn lib files, in windows install [JavaHL](http://subclipse.tigris.org/wiki/JavaHL) plugin through install new software under Help menu , while in linux install lib through terminal using `yum or apt-get install libsvn-java` (depends on your operating system)

Comment: all those were installed ,but it doesn't work at all!I had tried three   versions of eclipse,none of it work ,I also deleted  the files in the package named "auth",well ,my computer is WIN7.Maybe any other problems ?Thank you !

Comment: did you changed svn client in preference to SVNKit, try disable firewall. and also try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10353198/subclipse-and-eclipse-ra-layer-request-failed)

Comment: yes ，I tried ，but it seems don't work still,I don't know what to say,now the log is " Unable to connect to a repository at URL"

Comment: it seems not other qustions but DNS ,I am sorry ,I change it from Fixed to automatic，and then it works!This has troubled me for so long.Thank you for help me ,thank you ...

Comment: good to hear that this issue is closed.